# Vue/Nuxt lifecycle calling a promise in beforecreate and the getter in created

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex

I am attempting to do a set of a variable in my beforeCreate() for a component and then in the created() get that variable. Essentially I need to set the variable in my store then get that variable. My created calls an action that runs an axios promise that commits the data to the state, and I have a getter in the store that I want to call in my created() to get that data.

I know I am getting the correct data back from my promise as I can see it in my console log, I just cant seem to get that data from my getter.

It doesn't seem to want to work, and I think it has to do with the fact that axios has not returned the promise yet? How can I ensure that my created() waits until the axios promise has been returned in beforeCreate()?

Sample code

..... Component....

```
data(){
  return{currentUser: null}
},
beforeCreate(){
  this.$store.dispatch('users/setCurrent')
}, 
created(){
 this.currentUser = this.$store.getters['users/current'].displayname
}
```

......Store.....

```
export const state = () => ({
  current: {}
});

export const mutations ={
  setCurrent: (state, c) => (state.current = c)
}

export const getter = {
  current: state => state.current
}

export const actions = {
setCurrent({commit, dispatch, rootState}){
   this.$axios.$get('/api/user/current', {headers: rootState.sessionUser.current})
   .then(res => {
     console.log(res)
     commit("setCurrent" res)
  })
}
```

Comment: Jamie, why don't you dispatch your action in the created hook and then use a computed property for the store getter?

Comment: I am trying that as well for some reason when I create a currentUser(){ console.info('displayname', this.$store.state.users.current.displayname) return this.$store.state.users.current.displayname} 

The displayname console.info gets called twice and overwrites my data??

Comment: Jamie where are you creating the currentUser method? Anyways if you try what I suggested I don't think you would have any data overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wait for response in your actions:

```
export const actions = {
  async setCurrent({commit, dispatch, rootState}){
    await this.$axios.$get('/api/user/current', {headers: rootState.sessionUser.current})
      .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      commit("setCurrent" res)
  })
}
```

and then in created or mounted hook :

```
async created() {
  await this.$store.dispatch('users/setCurrent')
  this.currentUser = this.$store.getters['users/current'].displayname
}
```